# Convert a PNG file to matrix

Tags: image-conversion

I need help in converting a png image back to the original values calculated in MATLAB.  I originally downloaded a RADAR image and used xlim & ylim to to plot a zoomed area, then I used the command line (saveas(gca, [opath 'VS',num2str(k),'L',num2str(LL)], 'png')) to save the image to a png file.  Now, I am trying to take the png file and convert it back to the original pre-saved matrix.  The problem is I do not get the exact values back, as I originally had.  I have a couple of colleagues who have also tried and we cannot get the original numbers.  **Can anyone help?**  I can provide a pre-saved matrix, lat & lon file (1832 x 720), the plot routine that I use xlim & ylim, the save line, then the routine that takes the png file and tries to return it to the original pre-saved plotted size.

```
for i=1%:length(tt)
imgpath2=[imgpath tt(i).name];
          map=colormap(jet(256));
          RGB=imread(imgpath2);
          S=rgb2ind(RGB,map);
          S=double(S);
          L=size(map,1);
          out=interp1(1:L,linspace(min_org,max_org,L),S(:,:));
%Turns white spaces into NaNs
          out(out==27.176470588235293)=NaN;
% pixels around campus
          ave=nanmean(nanmean(out(cam_wid,cam_len))); 
          testR=out(cam_wid,cam_len);
          testR2=10.^(testR./10);
          br=nanmean(testR2(:));
          rr(i)=(br/300)^(1/1);
        end
```